# Download Survey123 photos attachment with Python using their GlobalID?

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I need to download photos from Surve123 which are stored on ArcGIS server. Now I can download all photos from survey at once, but I need to download them separetely according on their GlobalID.

Now I'm using this code:

```
myPortal = "https://www.arcgis.com"
username = "my_user_name"
featureItemID = "myFeatureItemID"
outputPath = r"c:\temp"

myGIS = GIS(myPortal, username)

myFLItem = myGIS.content.get(featureItemID)
attachLayer = myFLItem.layers[0]
OIDField = attachLayer.properties.objectIdField
myRecord = attachLayer.query(where='1=1', out_fields=OIDField)
for r in myRecord.features:
    myOID = r.get_value(OIDField)
    attachmenets = attachLayer.attachments.get_list(myOID)
    for attachmenet in attachmenets:
        myDownload = attachLayer.attachments.download(oid=myOID,
                                                      attachment_id=attachmenet['id'],
                                                      save_path=outputPath)
        print("Downloaded: " + myDownload[0])
```

Is there some spot in this code where I can specify GlobalID of each photo?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this script which does something similar: https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-10441-downloading-feature-layer-attachments#comment-63348

There is a comment which specifies how to get the Global ID - just search 'attachmentGlobalId' after opening the page and it will show the changes that have to be made.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implemet this part to my code and I'll see how it works.

Comment: I'm not able to use your script. It's because I have different type of object. If I run "display(itemObject)" I get <Item title:"test" type:Form owner:some.owner>. So on the next lines "itemObject.layers" can not be proceed.

Comment: OK, i get that I put a wrong feature ID and I get back the Survey123 form layer. But I have another question. How I can get feature ID of Survey123 answer? I have JSON file using webhook and I need its feature ID to access it via ArcGIS Online.